# How to open a exe file located in client PC from hosted asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, host

I developed a small ASP.NET application to open an `exe` file located on my local PC. It is working fine when I run the application locally. But after hosting it in the `IIS server`, it generates an error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Code:

```
var fullpath = @"C:\Users\xxx\printCrystalReport.exe";

var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = fullpath;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 

// This line generates the error
p.Start();                                    

p.WaitForExit(10000);
p.Close();
```

Please help me to solve this error or any other way to open this `exe` from the hosted application. Thank you

Comment: The ASP.NET code runs on the web server, not your PC.

Comment: Have you verified that your program has proper permissions to read or execute the .exe file? Your code assumes it does, maybe perform a check on the file and wrap your code in a try/catch to handle permissions or file not found exceptions.

Comment: Can we also mention how *bad it would be* from a security standpoint if a hosted server could possibly start an executable on the client?

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right, we can't run your `printCrystalReport.exe` file in client side.

I suggest you can learn some services like online office tools, something like: [Microsoft office online services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api) or [Google Sheets API Overview](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts), and so on.

The cloud services about this can store file in their cloud storage or personal cloud drive, it can help us save storage in web server. And we can online edit it. We just need to save the file link in our database.